# Namespace use and abuse in a big library

Tags: c++, coding-style, namespaces

I'm currently pondering what could be a way to make my (reasonably) big library look not too fat, and some contributor suggested using several namespaces to categorize things.

Whilst I understand the need to make things clear for users of this lib, I have a doubt that namespaces would be an appropriate solution, because it makes writing code much more verbose ie something like :

```
namespace1::namespace2::namespace3::SomeClass myObject* = new namespace1::namespace2::namespace3::SomeClass();
```

What's the general use of this c++ feature among the community?

Would a single namespace for the whole library + naming convention for classes, or \addtosection in doxygen docs be better?

Comment: Splitting the fat library into orthogonal small libraries is not an option ?

Comment: @AlexandreC. actually, the library is not that fat (20-30 cpps), but it needs grouping functionnality for clarity. Splitting into components may become an option if the library really grows big...

Answer (score 2):

> **Would a single namespace for the whole library?**

The main aim of namespaces is to avoid the problems of similar symbol names and the resulting symbol name clashes.
It is much better to have a single namespace for your library and meaningful indicative class names.This would serve the purpose of avoiding name clases as well as not too clumsy.

You could always use,

- [Using Namespace declarations](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc/language/ref/using_declaration.htm) or
- [Namespace aliases](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/topic/com.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc/language/ref/creating_a_namespace_alias.htm)

in case you have nested namespaces which you cannot avoid for whatever reasons.

Comment: Easier said than done. Sometimes the same name can be meaningful in many contexts and chances are you have both contexts in your library. Consider `Expression`.

Comment: @pmr: That is perception based and matter of choice/preference, it can be debated endlessly.

Comment: I know, I just wanted to point out that it is not as easy as you make it sound.

Comment: @pmr: And not as difficult as you make it sound either.

Comment: Personally I like just good ol' fashioned prefixes. No worrying about ADL, reduced likelihood of clashes with external libraries for those who write using declarations/definitions often, easier to forward declare types, etc. That said, I much prefer a single namespace for a library than one that involves nested namespaces. It seems a bit ill-coordinated for a single library to have to worry about clashes within its own namespace.

Answer (score 1):

Deep namespace levels can be made pretty with namespace aliases, so I wouldn't consider this much of a problem. That's also something you cannot do with naming conventions that prefix class names with a module name.

I consider organisation in doxygen to be orthogonal to the actual naming. If your code does not have clear include dependencies, doxygen groups are the way to go. Otherwise I provide file level documentation and a guide to the file hierarchy in form of a doxygen page. That way I don't need to group things manually and sanity check my includes at the same time.

Comment: Asking about downvoting in the comments is not an appropriate use of comments (not only because it's futile, because there's no one to notify, but also because it's noise, comments are meant for clarification on the post, not for meta discussions).  Please refrain from doing so in the future.

Answer (score 0):

This is the approach used by Boost. But Boost is a *collection* of libraries, each inside their own namespace.

Inside functions, you can make use of `using` directives to lighten things a little if needed, like `using namespace std::placeholders`, or `using std::placeholders::_1`.

Or you can use namespace aliases: `namespace ns = name1::name2::name3`.

The best overall is really to make several small independent libraries which make as few assumptions about each other, and give them a different namespace. If this is not possible, you may want to review the general design.